# Convert a tcl file to a exe fail

Tags: dll, tcl, exe

I've tried to convert a tcl file to a exe file by using FREEWRAP.EXE .
It works on most of the files, but there is one file which includes a line of code "load TLTcl.dll " which will always fail.

When I run the tcl file with activetcl, it was fine. 
Since I convert the tcl file to a exe file and put TLTcl.dll on the same folder with it, the exe always crash while executing.

I wonder how to load a dll file in the tcl file when I turn a tcl to a exe. 
Thanks a lot !

```
puts "Starting FLASH script" 
puts "FLASH write will be performed now, make sure you have an extra flash... " 
#load 10 lira tcl DLL 
load TLTcl.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `TLTcl.dll` was not built with stubs support, which means that it links against a real `tcl.dll` (possibly with a version number in the name) and freewrap doesn't use that; it uses a statically-linked build so that the whole system can be a simply-redistributable file.

You'll need to rebuild TLTcl.dll with stubs support enabled (assuming it is a DLL that implements a Tcl extension). That's not usually too difficult, as it is a matter of defining the `USE_TCL_STUBS` preprocessor symbol when compiling all the files, and linking against the `tclstub` static library; it probably has the version number embedded in the filename (and the version of the Tcl headers you compile with and the stub library you link with *must* match). Note that it is a property of Tcl's API that if you build against the Tcl 8.5 stubbed API, you can be loaded into a Tcl 8.6 interpreter. (Indeed, that level of forward compatibility is there from about 8.0.6<sup>†</sup> through to 8.7, which is still in active development so you won't be using it yet.)

---

<sup><sup>†</sup>This was a version that was only released to a few commercial partners. Everyone else used newer *supported* versions.</sup>